# react-native-camera error when compiling android - cannot find symbol class NonNull

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, non-nullable

**package.js**

```
...
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.5",
"react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git"
...
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'

include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
```

**settings.gradle**

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
...
```

**gradle.properdies**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Error

../../../../../../../../node_modules/react-native-camera/android/src/main/java/com/google/android/cameraview/Camera2.java (3 errors)

error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
error: cannot find symbol class NonNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is caused by google migrating to [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

A first quick-fix would be to delete the imports / annotation by hand in your /node-modules/

You need to :

- first find the Camera2.java file (the one raising the error)
- then find the `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;` line and delete it
- also delete every @NonNull annotation being used in the file

Mike Hardy created a package allowing you to do this automatically : https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#to-jetify--convert-node_modules-dependencies-to-androidx (it's react-native / npm friendly)

You will need to do this for every packages if they are using those annotations.

Also keep in mind that some packages might be using java classes located at : `android.support.v4` (such as ActivityCompat, NotificationCompat, ...) those classes are now located here `androidx.core.app.*`  (androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat, ...) due to the androidx migration

Some references :

- https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/686
- https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#to-jetify--convert-node_modules-dependencies-to-androidx

Here is a class mapping csv file between old / new android imports :

https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier/blob/master/src/androidx-class-mapping.csv